# DB Migration on a Load-Balanced Cloud Foundry Deployment

Tags: database-migration, cloud-foundry

I'm deploying an app on cloud foundry. I also run a db migration before the deployment. To do this, my launch command looked like:

```
./run_migration && ./run_app
```

That was working well on 1 instance, but now I have 2 instances, so the launch command was changed to:

```
[ $CF_INSTANCE_INDEX != 0 ] || ./run_migration && ./run_app
```

This way the migration runs only on the instance number 0. And this works as well. However, once the migration failed.

```
2019-02-12T13:56:45.27+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT Exit status 1
2019-02-12T13:56:45.28+0100 [CELL/SSHD/0]OUT Exit status 0
OK

requested state: started
instances: 2/2

     state      since                    cpu     memory        disk
#0   starting   2019-02-12 01:56:36 PM   0.0%    0 of 1G       0 of 1G
#1   running    2019-02-12 01:56:39 PM   15.8%   93.3M of 1G   249.4M of 1G
```

So as far as I understand, the puch is considered to be healthy although only one instance manages to start.

Is there a way to fail the push when not all instances managed to start

Comment: What version of the cf cli are you using?

Comment: Nm, seeing the same as you on the latest cf cli.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to fail the push when not all instances managed to start

I don't know of a way to do that, but you could always follow up and check after `cf push` completes.

Run `cf app <app> | grep 'instances:'` and you should see the number running and total requests. If they don't match something's up.

If you're just trying to make your deployment script fail, doing a check like that, while a little more work, should suffice. If there's some other reason, you'll need to add some background to your question so we call understand the use case better.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, it's all about the concept. Previously when I pushed there will be a migration, then start of the app. If all went well, then I have a new version of the app. If something failed then I the still the old version of the app. Now when I have two instances, it doesn't seem that I can have a "holistic" deployment with CF. I have to deploy, and then check for something and then maybe rollback…

Comment: `If something failed then I the still the old version of the app.` - I don't think that's true. When you push, the platform is going to stop your app, stage the new app and then try to start it. You app will be down and if it fails to start, it'll be in the crashing state until you fix it. You might be able to restart with the old droplet, but it's not part of the standard push cycle.

Comment: What you need to do to get a clean no-downtime upgrade for you app is blue/green deployment. I'm not sure how that would work with your db migrations running on the first instance.

Comment: The other thing you probably want to consider is that when you have multiple instances of your app they are starting in parallel. They're *not* going to wait on the first instance to start. Thus if your DB migration takes a minute to complete, the other app instances will be up and at least trying to run for a minute while the DB migration runs.

Comment: Last thing for now. If you haven't seen tasks, you might want to look at those. It's another option to run migrations on CF -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html#use-cases.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I deploy with a zero-downtime-push which does blue/green deployment automatically. I was just supposing that there is some approach to db migrations, because also I've read some docs that suggested to check for instance #0 and so on. But now it seems that there is no simple solution. I will revert to having only one instance and think. Maybe I'll fork the sero-downtime plugin and add a migration to it